# Updating an existing row with new columns and values in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, row

My Problem is the following:

I have an dataframe with appid as the index:

```
appid                     name                         
1648300          Costume Party
1648310  Pillars Of Protection
1648340                Push Me
1648350  Fret Smasher Playtest
1648360               Luminary
...                        ...
```

and iteratively recalling information per appid/index, resulting in a new dataframe (or optional Series)

```
 num_reviews  review_score review_score_desc  total_positive  ...
0            0             0   No user reviews               0 ...
```

I would now like to now append the new ones in every iteration, such that in the first iteration new columns are generated in the original df from the ones in the new one. It should look like

```
appid                     name  num_reviews  review_score review_score_desc  total_positive  ...                         
1648300          Costume Party  0            0.           0.                 0
1648310  Pillars Of Protection. 1.           2.           3.                 4.                      
1648340                Push Me  ...
1648350  Fret Smasher Playtest
1648360               Luminary
...                        ...
```

I do not want to create a new frame or add new columns, but update the existing one.

I tried

`df.loc[appid] = df.loc[appid].append(pd.DataFrame(new_data))` 
and

```
df.loc[appid] = pd.concat([df.loc[appid], pd.Series(new_data)])
```

Which are both not working.

Also just inserting the values does not work, since the columns are not generated in the first iteration.

Does anyone knows an answer to this ?
I was looking quite a lot and was unable to find something usefull.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

**Example**

i make simple and minimal example for answer

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['name1', 'name2'], index=['A', 'B'], columns=['col1'])
iter1 = pd.DataFrame([[0, 1]], index=['A'], columns=['col2', 'col3'])
iter2 = pd.DataFrame([[2, 3]], index=['B'], columns=['col2', 'col3'])
```

`df`

```
    col1
A   name1
B   name2
```

`iter1`

```
    col2    col3
A   0       1
```

`iter2`

```
    col2    col3
B   2       3
```

---

**Code**

at first concat iteratively recalling information dataframe(iter1, iter2) and concat with `df`

```
pd.concat([df, pd.concat([iter1, iter2])], axis=1)


    col1    col2    col3
A   name1   0       1
B   name2   2       3
```

in my code, iter1 & iter2 was concated, but you can be combined in your `for` loop.

Comment: Ok thanks! I did it this way now, first concatenating all iters, and then after the iteration is finished to the original frame. But would it be possible also directly concatenating them in the for loop, row by row ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the question correctly, you start with a dataframe containing appid and name (df1). While iterating, we receive some new data for a given appid (df2). If df2 contains new columns, we append the columns to df1. Finally, write all values from df2 into the corresponding fields in df1.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# initial dataframe containing appid and name
df1 = pd.DataFrame([['Costume Party'],['Pillars Of Protection'],['Push Me']],
                   index=[1648300, 1648310, 1648340],
                   columns=['name'])

# some new data for a given appid
appid = 1648340
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1,5,'positive']],
                   index=[appid],
                   columns=['num_reviews','review_score','review_desc'])

# append columns from df2 if they are not already in df1
cols_to_add = df2.columns
for col in cols_to_add:
  if col not in df.columns:
    df1[col] = np.nan


# write values for appid from df2 into df1
cols_to_write = df2.columns
df1.loc[appid, cols_to_write] = df2.loc[appid]

df1
```

Output:

```
| appid   | name | review_score | review_desc | num_reviews |
|:--------|:-----|:-------------|:------------|:------------|
| 1648300 | Costume Party         | NaN | NaN      | NaN |
| 1648310 | Pillars Of Protection | NaN | NaN      | NaN |
| 1648340 | Push Me               | 5.0 | positive | 1.0 |
```

Comment: The problem here is that df2 is generated newly for every appid, over which I am iterating. I do not want another for loop inside where I have to iterate over the columns every time. I want them to be automatically added to the first one in each step, without creating a second dataframe to store them first.

Comment: During the loop, when you call get_new_data(appid), does that return a dataframe or something else? Is there a way to validate beforehand the set of all columns that get_new_data() can return?